# ImportError: No module named pydevd_vm_type

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2.6.3 and Python 2.7.5 for my Google Application Engine project.
Today occurred strange error when I was trying to debug my GAE project:

```
ImportError: No module named pydevd_vm_type
```

Module exists but doesn't want to be imported somewhere in debug tools.
When I trying to type "import pydevd_vm_type", autocomplete tool gives me right path to that module. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
File Path_on_disk\PyCharm 2.6.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py

Error occurs in class

```
class PyDBCommandThread(PyDBDaemonThread)
```

in method

```
def OnRun(self)
...
    import pydevd_vm_type
    if pydevd_vm_type.GetVmType() == pydevd_vm_type.PydevdVmType.JYTHON and sys.hexversion <= 0x020201f0:
        # a lot of comments about Jython bug
        run_traced = False
```

and next in

```
import pydevd_tracing
if run_traced:
    pydevd_tracing.SetTrace(None) # no debugging on this thread
```

I've deleted those two imports. PROFIT!!!